# merge two JSON schemas (extend a JSON schema)

Tags: json, inheritance, merge, jsonschema

I have a "parent" JSON schema that I would like to extend to get various "child" schemas.  I'll have about 20 children so it's important for me to find something consistent here.

Here's the parent (base schema):

```
  {
    "definitions":{
      "selector":{
        "$id":        "#/definitions/selector",
        "type":       "object",
        "title":      "Selectors used to extract datas.",
        "required":   [],
        "properties":{
          "path":{
            "type":     "string",
            "title":    "Selector path",
            "default":  "",
            "examples": []
          },
          "attr":{
            "type":     "string",
            "title":    "HTML attribute",
            "default":  "",
            "examples": ["src"]
          },
          "regex":{
            "type":     "string",
            "title":    "Regex pattern",
            "default":  "",
            "examples": []
          },
          "multiple":{
            "type":     "boolean",
            "title":    "Multiple values",
            "default":  false,
            "readOnly": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Track importer schema",
  "properties":{
    "artist":{
      "$ref": "#/definitions/selector",
      "title": "Track artist"
    },
    "title":{
      "$ref": "#/definitions/selector",
      "title": "Track title"
    },
    "album":{
      "$ref": "#/definitions/selector",
      "title": "Track album"
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the child (based on the parent)

```
  {
    'properties':{
      'artist':{
        'properties':{
          'path':{
            'default':'.//artist',
            'readOnly':true
          }
        }
      },
      'title':{
        'properties':{
          'path':{
            'default':'.//title',
            'readOnly':true
          }
        }
      },
      'album':{
        'properties':{
          'path':{
            'default':'.//album',
            'readOnly':true
          }
        }
      },
      'image':{
        'properties':{
          'path':{
            'default':'.//albumart',
            'readOnly':true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I would like to get a new schema that would be the *sum* of the parent and child schemas.

Actually, I've found a way to have this working in Ruby by deep merging the two JSON schemas objects.

But since I need to use the schemas in multiple languages (Ruby, JavaScript, etc.), I would like to know if there is a way to do this "natively" with the JSON schemas.

Is that possible and how ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

```
"allOf": [
  { "$ref": "schema1.json" },
  { "$ref": "schema2.json" }
]
```

There is also the `$dynamicAnchor` and `$dynamicRef` keywords, which let you augment particular definitions with new properties, but it isn't necessary in your case because all of your properties are at the top level of the object, so two `$ref`s will work fine.

By the way, your `$id`s are invalid: identifiers cannot start with or include a fragment (at least not in any specification version that permits using `$ref` alongside other keywords, i.e. draft2019-09 or later).

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me more about my $id being invalid?  I don’t get it…

Comment: Basically, he value of the `$id` keyword cannot contain `#`.  The ids you have there don't add any value anyway, as `#/foo/bar` already means "location /foo/bar relative to the current base URI", which is the root of your document.
[Reference](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.8.2)